# Can I use an old ADSL inline filter/splitter for a VDSL connection?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, adsl, vdsl

I have an old ADSL inline filter/splitter that plugged into my phone line which I used to use on my old internet setup:

[image]

I no longer need it, but someone else I know may need it for their Australian NBN *Fibre To The Node* connection (this uses similar technology to a standard VDSL connection)

So can this ADSL splitter be used with a VDSL connection? I've seen [similar newer products](https://www.jaycar.com.au/vdsl-adsl-in-line-splitter-filter/p/YT6083) that explicitly support VDSL connections, so if I can't use this one I'll probably buy one of those, but I just thought I'd check.

If it *is* possible to use this old one, is it practical? By that I mean, if I'm on a 50mbps down/20 up plan, will this adaptor limit the speeds to the maximum ADSL speeds (~8mbps D/1mbps U)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would purchase a new splitter as splitters do tend to go faulty over time, and they are not expensive devices.  I note that you really want to try and avoid splitters on VDSL.  (ie have a single in-wall splitter where the VDSL comes into the property if you can house your modem there.)

That said, it is likely an ADSL filter will work fine with VDSL - it is most likely made before VDSL was a thing.

https://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/2725176  has some relevant comments.

Comment: Thanks! I know that my adapter is at least older than me (its from 2002-3 i think and it's been working from then until we got rid of it when we switched to NBN last year) but I'll look at in-wall splitters as well. With regards to using the current adaptor I have, if it *does* work with VDSL would I have noticeably downgraded performance in terms of speed?

Comment: @Pigeonburger Probably not unless you are doing speed tests  - but I say this as an indictment as to how bad the Internet is in Aussie, and because I cant really tell the difference between VDSL and 100 megabit fibre in day-to-day use.

Comment: Just leaving this comment here to confirm that it did indeed work fine with VDSL - it got ~55mbps down and 20mbps up, the exact speeds that were paid for